# SQL Trigger firing incorrectly on a multi-row insert

Tags: t-sql, triggers, dynamic-sql, sql-insert

I have been wrestling with this one for a few days now. I have a table trigger in place that creates an audit record for each Insert, Update, or Delete action and places it in a corresponding audit table in a neighboring database. This new audit record contains the source tables primary key value, the action type, an XML snapshot of the record, current date, and current user.

Each of the above listed pieces of information are assigned\calculated from the INSERTED \ DELETED tables and assigned to parameter values, which are then passed to a stored procedure that executes a piece of dynamic SQL to INSERT the new record. For the sake of this question, the dynamic SQL is a simple INSERT statement (shown below):

```
        INSERT INTO [340bAudit].[aud].[TableName]
            (
                RecordID
                ,ActionType
                ,xml_snapshot
                ,ModifiedDate
                ,ModifiedBy
            )
            VALUES (@RecordPK 
                ,@action
                ,@data 
                ,GETDATE() 
                ,SYSTEM_USER 
                   )
```

This trigger appear to work fine as long as there is only a record being Updated, but once a situation occurs where multiple records are being updated in a single statement, I get this:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression. The statement has been terminated.

The trigger looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RollOver_onUpdate] ON [dbo].[RollOver]
AFTER INSERT, update, DELETE
FOR EACH ROW

AS

BEGIN

/******** Audit *******/

DECLARE @TableName varchar(50)
        ,@RecordPK varchar(10)
        ,@action char(1)
        ,@data xml 

SET @TableName = 'RollOver'
SET @RecordPK = (SELECT DISTINCT RollOverID FROM INSERTED)

SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
        SET @action =
            CASE
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                     THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
            ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
            END
    END

SET @data = CASE WHEN @action <> 'D' THEN (SELECT'<rows>' + (SELECT * FROM INSERTED i FOR xml PATH) + '</rows>')
                 ELSE (SELECT'<rows>' + (SELECT * FROM DELETED d FOR xml PATH) + '</rows>')
            END

--Execute Audit Record Creation
EXECUTE sp_CreateAuditRecord    @Table = @TableName
                                ,@RecordID = @RecordPK
                                ,@ActionType = @action
                                ,@XML = @data


END
```

Can I alter this trigger to execute by row in this case? And if not, where do I go from here?

I would very much like to retain the flexibility I have with the dyanamic SQL, as every table in my database uses this same audit logic and this is the first and only table that appears to have issue, which I believe is due to the 'use' of this table.

Comment: Take a look at Best Practice: Coding SQL Server triggers for multi-row operations http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/best-practice-coding-sql-server-triggers  make it set-based and get rid of the proc call

Comment: Looks like that link no longer works. Anyone have an alternative link to a similar resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It's definitely not the most elegant code, but it works and solves my issue. Thank you for the responses. I would vote one up but no one posted an answer for me to accept.

```
/******** Audit *******/

DECLARE @action char(1)

SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
            BEGIN
                SET @action =   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                                        THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
                                    ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
                                 END 

                INSERT INTO [340bAudit].[aud].[Orders]
                    (
                        RecordID
                        ,ActionType
                        ,xml_snapshot
                        ,ModifiedDate
                        ,ModifiedBy
                    )
                SELECT d.OrderID,
                       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                                        THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
                                    ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
                                 END ,
                       CASE WHEN @action <> 'D' THEN (SELECT'<rows>' + (SELECT * FROM INSERTED i FOR xml PATH) + '</rows>')
                            ELSE (SELECT'<rows>' + (SELECT * FROM DELETED d FOR xml PATH) + '</rows>') END,
                        GETDATE(), 
                        SYSTEM_USER 
                FROM DELETED d 
            END

        -- INSERTED Order Records
        INSERT INTO [340bAudit].[aud].[Orders]
            (
                RecordID
                ,ActionType
                ,xml_snapshot
                ,ModifiedDate
                ,ModifiedBy
            )
        SELECT i.OrderID,
                @action,
                (SELECT'<rows>' + (SELECT * FROM INSERTED i FOR xml PATH) + '</rows>'),
                GETDATE(), 
                SYSTEM_USER 
        FROM INSERTED i
```